# Does Flutter's provider package support ordered listeners?

Tags: flutter, observer-pattern, flutter-provider

does Flutter's [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) support the notion of ordered listeners?

In my concrete example I would like to make sure that a particular listener of my `ChangeNotifier` is executed before a `Consumer` widget of that change notifier.

If there's no specific feature for this purpose, can somebody tell me how Provider naturally orders the listeners of a ChangeNotifier? Does it solely depend on the registration time of the listener/consumer? (FIFO principle)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Consumer` isn't relying on listeners to work, but on a different mechanism (InheritedWidgets)

`Consumer.builder` isn't called during `notifyListeners`. It is called by the Flutter framework when building the Widget tree, which happens at a completely different time.

Comment: Thanks Rémi, I wasn't aware of the way Consumer works. But from what you're saying it's safe to assume that any listeners that were registered with the ChangeNotifier manually via  #addListener will be called before the widget tree rebuilds, right?